# Htaccess how to send all sub-domain visitors to "official" external url and avoid it being indexed

Tags: wordpress, apache

all runs in wordpress

The scenario is the following:

-Got a aditional domain, hosted in a `www.website.com/aditionalsite`
but the "real" url is `www.aditionalsite.com`

-I have to avoid by all means the indexation of `www.website.com/aditionalsite`

-Which lines in `.htaccess` file would do this, without affecting the `site www.website.com/` 
and maybe redirecting them to `www.aditionalsite.com`?

-This has to be done without hurting and to protect the SEO of the sites, and their main indexation pages.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that only www. is used for your domain (optional)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aditionalsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aditionalsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then you have to direct only your second domain to a new folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)aditionalsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/aditionalsite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /aditionalsite/$1
```

Then redirect every request to this folder from the wrong domain to the correct domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\).aditionalsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aditionalsite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.aditionalsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Indexing will not happen of pages who redirect with a 301.

You can check your headers on: http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to mess with .htaccess. On the root of the website, create file named "robots.txt". In that file, put the following 2 lines:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /aditionalsite/
```